# NoSQL for searching any arbitrary attribute value without specifying indexes in advance

Tags: nosql

I have spent a lot of time researching NoSQL systems to do something that sounds like it should be very common. I want to store JSON data (or any structured document I guess) then search on any tag/value pair.

The challenge is that I don't know ahead of time the top level attributes that will be contained in the  data, so I really want to avoid having to define every possible index ahead of time.

For example, I may have a lot of contacts such as

firstname: Bob
lastname: Smith
address: ...
city: Quincy

Some of the data set will have additional, solution specific attributes, such as:

twitter: @blah
gender: male

While others may have :

companyname: A great place to work 
companycity: Boston
yearsemployed: 7

I would like to be  able to search companycity = Boston AND city = Quincy for one data set and city = Boston AND gender = male without having to define those indexes initially.

So, despite the rather contrived example, what is the best nosql system for arbitrary searches of this type? Currently all I know of is using a full text indexing solution such as Lucene. Unless I have missed something, Cassandra, MongoDB, CouchDB all require indexes to be written ahead of time for any real performance.

A little extra info:

Each data set may be 100000 records. Searches are interactive.

Any help and links appreciated. If you have experience of real solutions doing this would be great.

Comment: Already checked out Elastic Search? http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Comment: Gah so tempting the promise of an accepted answer. =) I haven't worked directly with Elastic, just overheard things at work. We've had lots of trouble with Solr and are replacing it with Elastic. Both are built on top of Lucene though. You can definitely insert heterogeneous documents into Elastic. This page has good information about Elastic that I think will be valuable for your requirements. http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/basic-elasticsearch-concepts.html

Comment: Well, kudos to you for the honesty. If I get some more real experience in the coming days it looks like I'll be answering my own question, in a way which I hope is useful to others. Though please feel free to beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

[ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) provides the key requirements from my question (thanks to @ryan1234 for the tip). It provides support for rapid indexing and querying of data with a simple HTTP API.

- JSON documents automatically indexed
- arbitrary structured document schema
- searches defined at runtime
- no necessity to generate index or query definitions ahead of time
- scalability (I currently have about 10 million docs in 2GB memory instance)

Based on a few months experience using ElasticSearch on a couple of projects I'm definitely an advocate.